# How to extend StructuredTextEditor(or Text Editor) content assistant for HTML

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to dynamically extend content assistant for HTML - for example:
-add new tags, attributes and attributes values
-for this code:

```
<div class="someClass">
...
</div>
<div class=$>
..
```

cursor position is $. I would like to add "someClass" to the displayed proposals.

The question is - what is the best way to do that? Is it better to extend HTMLTagsCompletionProposalComputer, connect it to the extension point and override computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalInvocationContext, IProgressMonitor) or maybe there is a better solution? Some good tutorial or example would be very helpful. The most important thing - i need to do this dynamically, so adding new templates it's not good solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best place is inside eclipse.

I dont think this should be a extra-plugin. Dont you think you better contribute to the eclipse development itself? If so:

1. Download the Eclipse-Sources
2. Add your Feature
3. Post the Fix to bugs-eclipse as an suggestion.

Regards